# need validation for contacts and accounts in suitecrm

Tags: php, validation, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am using SuiteCRM 7.7.9 version. while creating note i have a fields like Contact and Related to. In Contact we can click icon and we can select the contact from the list and Related to filed i have Account and Account Name("DRDP") will display automatically .

So here i want validation for particular contact is related to Account Name ("DRDP") or not.if not then we should show the message that it not related to this account.same like vice versa.

Can you help me how can i do it?

You can see below the image of the filters

[image]

Comment: Rather than validation, you should look into setting the account based on the selected contact, or limiting the contact lookup to those related to the linked account.  Unfortunately I don't have any code examples for this.

Comment: Martin,Thanks for your response. I posted this question in some forums but i didn't get proper answer. you are the only person gave me the solution.so you are the GOD now..:-).. i am sure you only can help me out in this.Please i am waiting for your solution.even i am new to this, your solution is very favor to me.

Comment: Udaya, look at the URL of the popup window for the relate field.  If you can append the Account ID to the query string you should be able to filter the options available.  You will need a different approach for the type-ahead search though.